# Hibernate HQL query error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql

I try to get result from Hibernate HQL query:

**from StopsRegister s where s.startTime>='2018-04-25 07:59:00.0' and s.endTime<='2018-04-26 07:59:00.0'**

**from StopsRegister s where s.startTime between '2018-04-25 08:42:00' and '2018-04-26 08:42:00'**

The issue starts when a add a secound date: and s.endTime<='2018-04-26 07:59:00.0' With only one value everything works correct.

But get the SQL Error:

**The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

That is the way i get the date values:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.of(toDatePicker.getDate(), toTimePicker.getTime()));
```

data types is: java.sql.Timestamp;
database: MS SQL Server.

In me opinion date format is correct, I do not understan this error.

Comment: Please provide some sample data that causes the error

Answer (score 0):

That solve the issue:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from StopsRegister s where s.startTime >= :from and s.startTime <= :to");
        q.setTimestamp("from", from);
        q.setTimestamp("to", to);
        stopRegisterList = (ArrayList<StopsRegister>) q.list();
```